# Networking All in one packages Vs Modem / Router Combinations

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

I have recently acquired a Modem and Wireless router package from Virgin Media.

The router has functions for wireless routing and for use as a modem.

Previously I was using a wireless router to connect to the internet upstairs and a seperate modem to provide me with access to the internet.

Now I have this all in one package the virgin SuperHub. Which evidently turns out isn't compatible with my wireless card so I'm using the SuperHub as a modem and my old wireless router for internet. Both are N standard 802.11 devices.

My question is to you think that this setup will have a noticable impact on network performance? Against the all-in-one Modem Router package?

I've checked their specifications and both are pretty much the same besides the wideband 5Ghz transmission capabilites which doesn't concern me since my computer is a fair distance from my wireless router.

My Router is the NetgearWNR2000

The Router/Modem package is a Virgin Superhub

Comment: Whether they are chained by external cables or not, you have multiple devices either way: modem, router, switch, wireless access point. It makes no difference how many devices you break them up into, it is all in the configuration. If you intend to use more than one device, ensure that only one device is routing so you avoid double NAT or multiple DHCP servers on the same network (unless you know precisely what you are doing).

Comment: The superhub has a modem setting so its working like a bog standard modem, the router is then connected directly to the modem. The router "Netgear WNR2000" has DHCP enabled and default routing settings. All routing functions are disabled on the SuperHub, I don't think their will be any issues regarding multiple DHCP or NAT servers. Do you think that one extra device will make any difference        to the networks performance?

Comment: It is the same number of devices, they are just setup differently. This actually gives you a bit more processing power and the load will be divided up a bit more. The router will be doing slightly less work as it doesn't have to take care of the modem functionality as well. This probably won't make too much of a difference though. For the most part, you won't likely notice any difference one way or the other with this setup.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Sweet didn't want to fork out more cash to get another wireless card for the sake of using this SuperHub thing. Which seems pretty cheap build quality anyway and is half the price of my stand alone router.

Answer (score 0):

With the two routing devices installed, you essentially have double NAT'd your network. This could potentially have catastrophic implications on your network performance.

This could work but you should configure your old wifi router in bridge mode.

Comment: It works fine there is a modem setting on the superhub which is enabled so it just works as a modem. I'm not getting any performance issues.

Comment: Would it slow down the networks performance in anyway? Seeing as the superhub has the same specifications as my router.

Comment: The 'modem' mode would be sufficient to prevent double-NAT and DHCP conflicts, and performance/reliability problems associated with either.  If you're not using the wifi of the superhub at all, it would be best to disable it.